# Trying to place buttons below a list view

Tags: java, android

So I'm creating a list view that grows and shrinks based off of the user input and I need four buttons but I don't know how to have buttons that are aligned with the bottom of the list view and are in a 2x2 grid fashion. I've already tried relative layout and it didn't seem to work. Thank you

Comment: The buttons should below the `ListView` and always visible at the bottom of the `Activity` regardless of how much space the `ListView` is requesting? :: Also please edit your question with the layout you have already tried so that can be used as a base for an answer

Comment: @Barns ya I want the 2x2 set of buttons at the bottom of the list regardless of how long it is

Comment: You can use `RelativeLayout`. Add the `Button` container first and pin it to the bottom of the Activity. Then add the `ListView` with `match_parent` attributes but above the `Button` container. That will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created the XML according to what I believed you wanted to see.
Please check the following screen shot: [image: screen shot here]

The following is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="BUTTON3"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="BUTTON4"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="BUTTON1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="BUTTON2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout2">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see that I am using the RelativeLayout as the base wrapper and within the RelativeLayout, I have 2 linearlayouts for the buttons (2 each) and finally the list view. The purpose for the LinearLayout is simply to add weight to the buttons so they would share the equal amount of horizontal space. If that does not fit your criteria, feel free to remove them. The **main thing** to learn is that relative layout allows you to use attributes such as **alignParenBottom, layout_above, layout_below and so on**. These attributes allow you to place your elements anywhere on the screen and adjust them according to these attributes. 
Let me know if you have any questions.